# How to refresh bonjour's service list?

Tags: python, networking, bonjour

Our application uses Bonjour to discover services on the network. In DNSServiceResolveCallback, when a new service is discovered, I'm sending a message to another part of the application that then proceeds to connect to the newly found server. A heartbeat mechanism allows us to detect connection failures immediately (unplugged cable for example).

Such failures are not detected by Bonjour itself straight away so I understand I need to manually invalidate Bonjour's cache.

But how ?

1. It seems that I need to call [DNSServiceReconfirmRecord](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/DNSServiceDiscovery_CRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/DNSServiceReconfirmRecord), but what options should I pass ? Especially, what my *fullname*, *rrtype* and *rdata* should be ? Apple provides [an example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Articles/ResolvingServices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001078-SW9) (see *When Resolving Fails*) but I don't really understand it.
2. After Bonjour's cache has been invalidated, where will I be notified that a service doesn't exist anymore ? In what callback ?
3. If the service comes back online again (network cable replugged), will I be notified in the browse callback ?

Answer (score 2):

Your brows callback should receive kDNSServiceFlagsAdd when a service is added. It has been sufficient for my uses to assume the service disappeared if the flag is not set. Do you have internal accounting of which services have been seen? Invalidating the whole cache every time something disconnected would cause quite a bit of network overhead.

This is my twisted specific wrapper
https://github.com/jlujan/twistpybonjour/blob/master/twistbonjour.py

**Update and fix:**

You will need to query the record to get the correct fields to pass to DNSServiceReconfirmRecord. Example is [here](https://github.com/nickstenning/pybonjour/blob/master/examples/browse_resolve_query.py)

Then try

```
pybonjour.DNSServiceReconfirmRecord(0, 
    interfaceIndex, 
    fullname, 
    rrtype, 
    rrclass, 
    rdata)
```

You will have to keep a reference to the relevant fields received in your resolve/query callback. The rrtype field is the type of record, usually kDNSServiceType_SRV. rrclass is always kDNSServiceClass_IN as this is the only one defined.

Comment: Does that mean that you Browse on a regular basis (like every 5 seconds), build a list of discovered machines and compare it with a previous list ? I'm using *select* [as in this example](http://code.google.com/p/pybonjour/) and when a machine disappears the Browse callback is not called.

Comment: Browsing is continuous. You are basically registering with mDNS to receive notifications of new service broadcasts. the `if not (flags & pybonjour.kDNSServiceFlagsAdd):` in `browse_callback` in the example is doing what I described in my answer.

Comment: If you are using those examples directly, you should see service removals. This is the output of the browser and resolve after starting and stopping the register example

$ python bonjour.py _test._tcp
Service added; resolving
Resolved service:
  fullname   = TestService._test._tcp.local.
  hosttarget = Ripley.local.
  port       = 1234
Service removed
Service added; resolving
Resolved service:
  fullname   = TestService._test._tcp.local.
  hosttarget = Ripley.local.
  port       = 1234

Comment: I do see services removal when a service gets unregistered. However, if the connection is lost (ethernet cable unplugged), the local Bonjour browser won't be notified as Bonjour keeps a local cache of discoverer services that has a pretty long TTL.

Comment: pybonjour does not appear to return the error code from DNSServiceReconfirmRecord.